# Dropdown navigation bar using with parallax

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, parallax, nav

So I'm trying to design a website for my organization from scratch using Bootstrap and with parallax elements. And I found this demo online and all I want to do is add a navigation bar with one of the buttons having a hovering dropdown menu. I followed the instructions on the Bootstrap website and gettting the bar on the page is easy but the hovering drop down does not appear or if i do get the bar up the dropdown menu is messed up, putting it to the right. It seems that there is a Z-axis problem? Or the container for the nav bar isnt letting me have a nice dropdown menu. Below is what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0060)https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm -->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #777;
    }
    
    .nav {
      background-color: #333;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999999;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:last-child a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:first-child a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      width: 210px;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .parallax-header {
      /* The image used / background-image: url("header.jpg"); / Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .bgimg-1,
    .bgimg-2,
    .bgimg-3 {
      position: relative;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .bgimg-1 {
      background-image: url("vsa2017.jpg");
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .bgimg-2 {
      background-image: url("culturedance.png");
      min-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .bgimg-3 {
      background-image: url("culturedance.png");
      min-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .caption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .caption span.border {
      background-color: #111;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 18px;
      font-size: 25px;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    }
    
    h3 {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #111;
    }
    /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
    
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      .bgimg-1,
      .bgimg-2,
      .bgimg-3 {
        background-attachment: scroll;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#home">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Pillars</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="family.html">Family</a>
        <a href="culture.html">Culture</a>
        <a href="diversity.html">Diversity</a>
        <a href="cpp.html">Philanthropy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="officers.html">Officers</a>
    <a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gmu.vsa?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gmuvsa/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>


  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">SCROLL DOWN</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Parallax Demo</h3>
    <p>Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling. Nascetur per nec posuere turpis, lectus nec libero turpis nunc at, sed posuere mollis ullamcorper libero
      ante lectus, blandit pellentesque a, magna turpis est sapien duis blandit dignissim. Viverra interdum mi magna mi, morbi sociis. Condimentum dui ipsum consequat morbi, curabitur aliquam pede, nullam vitae eu placerat eget et vehicula. Varius quisque
      non molestie dolor, nunc nisl dapibus vestibulum at, sodales tincidunt mauris ullamcorper, dapibus pulvinar, in in neque risus odio. Accumsan fringilla vulputate at quibusdam sociis eleifend, aenean maecenas vulputate, non id vehicula lorem mattis,
      ratione interdum sociis ornare. Suscipit proin magna cras vel, non sit platea sit, maecenas ante augue etiam maecenas, porta porttitor placerat leo.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-2">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">LESS HEIGHT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-3">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">SCROLL UP</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">COOL!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I'm fairly new and need to learn, any help will be appreciated/

Answer (score 1):

Here solution:

Just put 2 style in class name `.dropdown-content` css:

```
top: 100%;
background: #333;
```

New update style is ".dropdown"
 Replace style:`display:inline-block;` to `float:left;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0060)https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm -->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #777;
    }
    
    .nav {
      background-color: #333;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float:left;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999999;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      background: #333;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:last-child a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:first-child a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      width: 210px;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .parallax-header {
      /* The image used / background-image: url("header.jpg"); / Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .bgimg-1,
    .bgimg-2,
    .bgimg-3 {
      position: relative;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .bgimg-1 {
      background-image: url("vsa2017.jpg");
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .bgimg-2 {
      background-image: url("culturedance.png");
      min-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .bgimg-3 {
      background-image: url("culturedance.png");
      min-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .caption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .caption span.border {
      background-color: #111;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 18px;
      font-size: 25px;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    }
    
    h3 {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #111;
    }
    /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
    
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      .bgimg-1,
      .bgimg-2,
      .bgimg-3 {
        background-attachment: scroll;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#home">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Pillars</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="family.html">Family</a>
        <a href="culture.html">Culture</a>
        <a href="diversity.html">Diversity</a>
        <a href="cpp.html">Philanthropy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="officers.html">Officers</a>
    <a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gmu.vsa?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gmuvsa/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>


  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">SCROLL DOWN</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Parallax Demo</h3>
    <p>Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling. Nascetur per nec posuere turpis, lectus nec libero turpis nunc at, sed posuere mollis ullamcorper libero
      ante lectus, blandit pellentesque a, magna turpis est sapien duis blandit dignissim. Viverra interdum mi magna mi, morbi sociis. Condimentum dui ipsum consequat morbi, curabitur aliquam pede, nullam vitae eu placerat eget et vehicula. Varius quisque
      non molestie dolor, nunc nisl dapibus vestibulum at, sodales tincidunt mauris ullamcorper, dapibus pulvinar, in in neque risus odio. Accumsan fringilla vulputate at quibusdam sociis eleifend, aenean maecenas vulputate, non id vehicula lorem mattis,
      ratione interdum sociis ornare. Suscipit proin magna cras vel, non sit platea sit, maecenas ante augue etiam maecenas, porta porttitor placerat leo.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-2">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">LESS HEIGHT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-3">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">SCROLL UP</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">COOL!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for, if i need to move the Pillars button to make it closer to the other buttons do i use the padding in the .dropdown CSS?

Comment: ok np, Just update below css:

.dropdown {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999999;
    }

Put float: left instead of display: inline-block;

Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...
 I have done some changes to your code
 try to understand
 if you don't get anything don't mind to comment it
 I haven't done any more changes so made it clear

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0060)https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm -->
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #777;
    }
    
    .nav {
      background-color: #333;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    .nav a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9999999;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background: #333;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:last-child a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:first-child a:hover,
    .dropdown-content a:focus {
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      width: 210px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: left;
     
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      
    }
    
    .parallax-header {
      /* The image used / background-image: url("header.jpg"); / Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .bgimg-1,
    .bgimg-2,
    .bgimg-3 {
      position: relative;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .bgimg-1 {
      background-image: url("vsa2017.jpg");
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .bgimg-2 {
      background-image: url("culturedance.png");
      min-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .bgimg-3 {
      background-image: url("culturedance.png");
      min-height: 400px;
    }
    
    .caption {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .caption span.border {
      background-color: #111;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 18px;
      font-size: 25px;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    }
    
    h3 {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
      color: #111;
    }
    /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */
    
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      .bgimg-1,
      .bgimg-2,
      .bgimg-3 {
        background-attachment: scroll;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#home">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Pillars
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href="family.html">Family</a>
        <a href="culture.html">Culture</a>
        <a href="diversity.html">Diversity</a>
        <a href="cpp.html">Philanthropy</a>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <a href="officers.html">Officers</a>
    <a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gmu.vsa?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gmuvsa/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>


  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">SCROLL DOWN</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Parallax Demo</h3>
    <p>Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling. Nascetur per nec posuere turpis, lectus nec libero turpis nunc at, sed posuere mollis ullamcorper libero
      ante lectus, blandit pellentesque a, magna turpis est sapien duis blandit dignissim. Viverra interdum mi magna mi, morbi sociis. Condimentum dui ipsum consequat morbi, curabitur aliquam pede, nullam vitae eu placerat eget et vehicula. Varius quisque
      non molestie dolor, nunc nisl dapibus vestibulum at, sodales tincidunt mauris ullamcorper, dapibus pulvinar, in in neque risus odio. Accumsan fringilla vulputate at quibusdam sociis eleifend, aenean maecenas vulputate, non id vehicula lorem mattis,
      ratione interdum sociis ornare. Suscipit proin magna cras vel, non sit platea sit, maecenas ante augue etiam maecenas, porta porttitor placerat leo.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-2">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">LESS HEIGHT</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-3">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">SCROLL UP</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
      <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">COOL!</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```